C# .NET Core worker service need to log to text file and database table based on settings
I have added Serilog for writing into a text file and custom provider for write into a SQL Server database table. The code works when I add any one, but if add both, Serilog only works. Please advise
builder.Services.AddLogging(configure =>
{
    configure.AddProvider(new SqlServerLoggerProvider(connectionString.Value, sqlServerMinimumLogLevel)); // Assuming custom provider implemented
});

var logFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "logs", "workerService-{Date}.txt");

builder.Services.AddSerilog(loggingBuilder =>
    loggingBuilder.MinimumLevel.Debug()
     .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024) // Limit each log file to 10 MB
);


AddSerilog removes any previous providers. Consider using Serilog's SQL Server sink instead of creating your own

The requirement is to store the error log into ELMA Table in SQL Server database which has "ELMA_Error" table and logged by ASP.NET Core APP. The challenge is we could not use ELMAH logger in Worker service since it is not web app. Can serilog be configured to call stored proc of ELMAH and pass the required value.

is there any way I can add serilog without removing custom log provider.

You could use package Serilog.Extensions.Logging then configure like below, this will not override other logger providers.
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File(logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Services.AddLogging(configure =>
{
    configure.AddSerilog(logger);
    configure.AddProvider(new SqlServerLoggerProvider(connectionString.Value, sqlServerMinimumLogLevel));   
});


@Qjang Fu: Your solution works. Thanks a lot. I moved serilog file name and  other setting to appsetting to make it configurable.
